# Azure Synapse Analytics Workspace Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-synapse

I have created an Azure Synapse Analytics Workspace in which I have pipelines with parameters. These parameters have storage account name, folder names etc which will change as we deploy the Synapse Analytics Workspace from Dev to Stage and Prod.

During the deployment in the Parameters file - I do not see pipeline parameters parameterized. Only Triggers and Linked services parameters are available as parameters in ARM Template.
In Azure Data Factory, we would define using arm-template-parameters-definition.json that which parameters need to be available in ARM Template parameters file.

Is there a similar option available in Synapse Workspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this article: [CICD Automation in Synapse Analytics: taking advantage of custom parameters in Workspace Templates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/cicd-automation-in-synapse-analytics-taking-advantage-of-custom/ba-p/3513546).

You would need to create a custom `template-parameters-definition.json` file. Then you will be able to add more customization.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful and resolved the issue.